# Applying a function element-wise on a vector or list would fail using sapply or lapply

Tags: r, function, vector, lapply, dna-sequence

I have the following vector `v`:

```
c("tactagcaatacgcttgcgttcggtggttaagtatgtataatgcgcgggcttgtcgt",
"tgctatcctgacagttgtcacgctgattggtgtcgttacaatctaacgcatcgccaa",
"gtactagagaactagtgcattagcttatttttttgttatcatgctaaccacccggcg")
```

i'm facing a very upsetting issue here. Each element of this vector is a DNA sequence. What i want to do is split each element 2 letters by 2 and obtain the count of occurrences of each pair of letters. The desired output would be exactly this for the first element:

```
AA AC AG AT CA CC CG CT GA GC GG GT TA TC TG TT 
 3  2  2  4  1  0  6  3  0  6  4  7  7  2  5  4
```

This result is achieved easily using the function [oligonucleotideFrequency](http://web.mit.edu/~r/current/arch/i386_linux26/lib/R/library/Biostrings/html/nucleotideFrequency.html). The problem is that this function will not apply over a list or a vector using sapply or lapply and i don't understand where is the problem and how to fix it.

If i do:

```
oligonucleotideFrequency(DNAString(v[1]), width = 2)
```

It works and i get this output:

```
AA AC AG AT CA CC CG CT GA GC GG GT TA TC TG TT 
 3  2  2  4  1  0  6  3  0  6  4  7  7  2  5  4
```

but if i do:

```
v <- DNAString(v)
lapply(v, oligonucleotideFrequency(v, width = 2)
```

This is what i get:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘oligonucleotideFrequency’ for signature ‘"list"
```

Same occurs with `sapply`.

If i check the class of `v` after applying the `DNAString` function it returns `"list"` so idon't get where is the problem here.

Even if i do:

```
oligonucleotideFrequency(v[1], width = 2)
```

it returns:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘oligonucleotideFrequency’ for signature ‘"list"’
```

I'm totally lost here, please help, i've been hours breaking my head into this, how can i fis this problem?? I want to apply this function to the whole vector at once.

PD: The R package containing this functions os called `Biostrings` and it can be downloaded and installed from [here](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Biostrings.html)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `lapply(v, oligonucleotideFrequency, width = 2)`

Comment: damn it. Tha worked!! I'm ashamed it was so simple. Thanks a lot really. Post it as an answer and i'll be more than happy to accept it

Comment: I have expanded my comment as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to use the `lapply` function.

The first one is to provide a user-defined function and set all the arguments inside the function like the following.

```
library(Biostrings)

v <- c("tactagcaatacgcttgcgttcggtggttaagtatgtataatgcgcgggcttgtcgt",
       "tgctatcctgacagttgtcacgctgattggtgtcgttacaatctaacgcatcgccaa",
       "gtactagagaactagtgcattagcttatttttttgttatcatgctaaccacccggcg")


lapply(v, function(x) oligonucleotideFrequency(DNAString(x), width = 2))
# [[1]]
# AA AC AG AT CA CC CG CT GA GC GG GT TA TC TG TT 
# 3  2  2  4  1  0  6  3  0  6  4  7  7  2  5  4 
# 
# [[2]]
# AA AC AG AT CA CC CG CT GA GC GG GT TA TC TG TT 
# 3  4  1  4  5  2  4  4  2  4  1  5  3  5  6  3 
# 
# [[3]]
# AA AC AG AT CA CC CG CT GA GC GG GT TA TC TG TT 
# 2  4  4  4  3  3  2  4  2  4  1  3  7  1  3  9
```

The second one is to provide the function name, and provide the arguemnts like `...` as follows. For this option, the item in the list (in this case, `v`), automatically goes to the first argument of the fucntion.

```
library(Biostrings)

v <- c("tactagcaatacgcttgcgttcggtggttaagtatgtataatgcgcgggcttgtcgt",
       "tgctatcctgacagttgtcacgctgattggtgtcgttacaatctaacgcatcgccaa",
       "gtactagagaactagtgcattagcttatttttttgttatcatgctaaccacccggcg")

v <- lapply(v, DNAString)

lapply(v, oligonucleotideFrequency, width = 2)
# [[1]]
# AA AC AG AT CA CC CG CT GA GC GG GT TA TC TG TT 
# 3  2  2  4  1  0  6  3  0  6  4  7  7  2  5  4 
# 
# [[2]]
# AA AC AG AT CA CC CG CT GA GC GG GT TA TC TG TT 
# 3  4  1  4  5  2  4  4  2  4  1  5  3  5  6  3 
# 
# [[3]]
# AA AC AG AT CA CC CG CT GA GC GG GT TA TC TG TT 
# 2  4  4  4  3  3  2  4  2  4  1  3  7  1  3  9
```

Comment: Thanks www!! This was exactly exactly what iw as looking for!! I must keep learning :)

Comment: Now i have one more question if i may: Imagine i have a dataframe and one of my features is the previous vector of the main question. I would like to make each pair of letters in the sequence become a feature of the dataframe and its value would be total count of all the pairs of letters.

it would be something like:

feature1: AA. feature 2: AC, and so on. and the values would be something like: for AA it should be 8, for AC 10, and so on for each feature. How could i achieve this?

Comment: @Miguel2488 I think I may know how to do this, but if you don't mind, could you ask a new question with a reproducible example, such as a data frame and the list you want to combine? I will study your reproducible example once you post it.

Comment: Allright, i'll create a new question and link it to you here when it's done. Give me a minute please :)

Comment: Hi www here's the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55462960/how-to-make-the-results-of-a-list-of-counted-values-become-one-hot-like-features). Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

```
x = c("tactagcaatacgcttgcgttcggtggttaagtatgtataatgcgcgggcttgtcgt",
      "tgctatcctgacagttgtcacgctgattggtgtcgttacaatctaacgcatcgccaa",
      "gtactagagaactagtgcattagcttatttttttgttatcatgctaaccacccggcg")

nc = c("a", "c", "t", "g")
lv = sort(Reduce(paste0, expand.grid(replicate(2, nc, simplify = FALSE))))
lapply(x, function(s)
    table(factor(sapply(seq(2, nchar(s), 1), function(i)
        substring(s, i - 1, i)),
        levels = lv)))
#[[1]]

#aa ac ag at ca cc cg ct ga gc gg gt ta tc tg tt 
# 3  2  2  4  1  0  6  3  0  6  4  7  7  2  5  4 

#[[2]]

#aa ac ag at ca cc cg ct ga gc gg gt ta tc tg tt 
# 3  4  1  4  5  2  4  4  2  4  1  5  3  5  6  3 

#[[3]]

#aa ac ag at ca cc cg ct ga gc gg gt ta tc tg tt 
# 2  4  4  4  3  3  2  4  2  4  1  3  7  1  3  9
```

Comment: Thank you d.b. it does the job indeed but what i was looking for was a way to implement the `oligonucleotideFrequency` function on the whole list