# How to make the results of a list of counted values become one-hot like features of a dataframe

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
v1        v2       v3
+         S10      tactagcaatacgcttgcgttcggtggttaagtatgtataatgcgcgggcttgtcgt
+        AMPC      tgctatcctgacagttgtcacgctgattggtgtcgttacaatctaacgcatcgccaa
+        AROH      gtactagagaactagtgcattagcttatttttttgttatcatgctaaccacccggcg
```

I perform a transformation on `v3` to split the strings each 2 letters and get the count of the ocurrences of each pair of letters like this:

```
lapply(df$v3, function(x) oligonucleotideFrequency(DNAString(x), width = 2))
```

this is the output of this transformation for the first string in v3:

```
AA AC AG AT CA CC CG CT GA GC GG GT TA TC TG TT 
3  2  2  4  1  0  6  3  0  6  4  7  7  2  5  4
```

Now i have all the value counts for each pair of letters in the strings of v3, but each count is separated and it does not provide a global value. Now what i would like to do, is to make each pair of letters become a feature of the dataframe where the value of each feature would be the number of occurrencies of each pair into the same string.

it would be something like this:

```
v1        v2     AA AC AG AT CA CC CG CT GA GC GG GT TA TC TG TT 
+         S10     3  2  2  4  1  0  6  3  0  6  4  7  7  2  5  4                        
+        AMPC     3  4  1  4  5  2  4  4  2  4  1  5  3  5  6  3 
+        AROH     2  4  4  4  3  3  2  4  2  4  1  3  7  1  3  9
```

How can i achieve this result?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using base R.

```
library(Biostrings)

dat <- read.table(text = "v1        v2       v3
'+'         'S10'      'tactagcaatacgcttgcgttcggtggttaagtatgtataatgcgcgggcttgtcgt'
'+'        'AMPC'      'tgctatcctgacagttgtcacgctgattggtgtcgttacaatctaacgcatcgccaa'
'+'        'AROH'      'gtactagagaactagtgcattagcttatttttttgttatcatgctaaccacccggcg'",
stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)

# Count the nucleotide number  
lst1 <- lapply(dat$v3, function(x) oligonucleotideFrequency(DNAString(x), width = 2))
# Transpose the vector and convert to a data frame for each element
lst2 <-  lapply(lst1, function(x) as.data.frame(t(x)))
# Comebine all single data frame into one data frame row-wise
dat2 <- do.call(rbind, lst2)
# Comebine with the original data frame column-wise
dat3 <- cbind(dat, dat2)
# Remvoe the v3 column
dat3$v3 <- NULL
dat3
#   v1   v2 AA AC AG AT CA CC CG CT GA GC GG GT TA TC TG TT
# 1  +  S10  3  2  2  4  1  0  6  3  0  6  4  7  7  2  5  4
# 2  + AMPC  3  4  1  4  5  2  4  4  2  4  1  5  3  5  6  3
# 3  + AROH  2  4  4  4  3  3  2  4  2  4  1  3  7  1  3  9
```

Comment: damn www that's amazing!! I owe you a good one, thanks again!! COuld you just explain a little bit what is the list part of the code doing?? for the sake of learning please

Comment: @Miguel2488 I provided some explanations. Thanks.